# Simple recursive subtraction returning unexpected result

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to figure out recursion for one of my projects. However it gives me an unexpected result where it starts working backwards after it hit the base case. I've made this simple snippet to demonstrate. If I pass this 3 to this method, the expected value would be 0. However it returns 2 as a result. Could someone explain why i starts increasing after it hits 0. Thanks in advance!

```
public static int sub(int i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        i--;
        sub(i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Your recursive call could be `i = sub(i);`

Comment: Since i is int which is a primitive type you should update i to reflect the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the value returned by `sub(i)`.

You can write:

```
public static int sub(int i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        i--;
        return sub(i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

or just

```
public static int sub(int i) {
    return (i > 0) ? sub(i-1) : i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also return from the intermediate calls:

```
public static int sub(int i) {
    if (i > 0) {
        i--;
        return sub(i);
    }
    return i;
}
```

So for instance, when you call sub(3), it would push to the stack a call to sub(2), then this to sub(1) and then to sub(0). At this point since `i>0` would be false, it would return 0.

Please check [Tutorial 18 - Recursion in Java](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PORo1ut9kMs), in order to see how the above works.